# Charindex in inner join affects the perfomance

Tags: sql, charindex

I have a procedure which has below query,

```
Select 
 a.column
,count(distinct(c.column))
from `table1` a with (nolock)
inner join `table2` b with(`nolock`) on a.id=b.id
inner join `table3` c with (`nolock`) on charindex(c.colum,a.column)>0
group by 
 a.column
```

table1 has almost 36,000 rows and query takes almost 40 seconds to load resultset.

a.column has fts index installed on it and it is xml datatype.

I tried to split the joins but results vary due to grouping.

How can I rewrite this query to make it more fast?

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing/joining one column on another you have to use the LIKE keyword. CHARINDEX, LEFT and RIGHT functions don't enable the SQL server to use the indexes.
What you're asking is if C.column is in A.Column,
Solution is:
instead of:

```
<CODE>
    charindex(c.column,a.column)>0
</CODE>
```

Use

```
<CODE>
    WHERE a.column LIKE '%' + c.column + '%'
</CODE>
```

Alternatively, try to strip the c.column so it would match the A.column.